# How to correctly read local text file content in django?

Tags: python, django

Good day, I'm receiving the following error, while trying to read from  a file:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'opened'
```

The error is coming from the bellow line in readFile:

```
if fileHandler['opened']:
```

and this is how my view looks like:
    from project.settings import text_file
    from django.core.files import File
    from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home_view(request):
    context = {'error': ''}
    readFile(context)
    render(request, 'index.html', context)


def readFile(context):
    fileHandler = open_file(context, 'r')

    if fileHandler['opened']:
        file = File(fileHandler['handler'])
        read_content(file, context)

        file.close()


def open_file(context, mode):
    try:
        fileHandler = open(text_file, mode)
        return {'open': True, 'handler': fileHandler}

    except IOError:
        context['error'] += 'Unable to open file.\n'
    except:
        context['error'] += 'Unexpected exception in openFile method.\n'
        return {'opened':False, 'handler': None}


def read_content(file, context):
    context['fileContent'] = ''
    for sentence in file.chunks(10):
        context['fileContent'] += sentence
```

and in me settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
text_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_file.txt')
```

Will really appreaciateany help.

Comment: You've set the key as 'open' as seen inside the open_file function and you're accessing an 'opened' key, which does not exist.

Comment: @AbhinavI thank you didn't notice it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the declaration of the function readFile in the third line of the view!

```
def home_view(request):
    context = {'error': ''}
    readFile(context) # HERE!
    render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Maybe your problem is here?

Comment: sorry typing mistake, I have replaced it